# $\langle g\rangle$ is $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G_\Delta$?

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Let $p$ be a prime and $G$ a primitive group of degree $n=p+k$ with $k\geq3$.

If $G$ contains an element of degree and order $p$. $G$ contains the cycle $(1,2 ... p)=g$. Let $\Delta= \lbrace p+1,p+2,...,n\rbrace$ and $\Gamma:=\lbrace1,2,...,p\rbrace$ that $\Delta ,\Gamma\subseteq \Omega$ that $\Delta\cup\Gamma=\Omega$ and $\Delta\cap\Gamma=\varnothing$.

Then can we say $\langle g\rangle$ is $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G_\Delta$ ?

Comment: That depends on whether $G_\Delta$ denotes the pointwise or the setwise stabilizer of $\Delta$.

Comment: $G_\Delta$ denotes the setwise stabilizer of $\Delta$

Comment: In that case the answer could be no if $n \ge 2p$, because $G$ could contain a $p$-cycle $(p+1,p+2,\ldots,2p)$, in which case $|G_\Delta|$ would be divisible by $p^2$.

Comment: In Wielandt's book on Permutation Groups, $G_\Delta$ denotes the pointwise stabilizer of $\Delta$. In that case, $G_\Delta$ is clearly isomorphic to the symmetric group on $\Gamma$, so $\langle g \rangle$ is indeed a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G_\Delta$.